# How to create a rounded TextFormField with Dropdhadow in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, frontend

So I'm trying to recreate this UI I created in Figma [image] using Flutter. I added rounded corners to the field and a drop shadow, but the drop shadow is still rectangular and it looks awful: [image]

I also want to change the color of the textfield to match the Figma prototype but I'm not sure how.

This is my code:

```
Material(
      elevation: 10.0,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'EMAIL',
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              color: Color(0xffA9A9A9),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: If you want a complete halfcircle at either end, use a StadiumBorder for your border.  It's exactly designed for that.  No hard math to figure out the border radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the same `borderRadius` to the `Material` widget too:

```
Material(
  elevation: 10.0,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'EMAIL',
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
          color: Color(0xffA9A9A9),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```